# Android: layouts with deallocated components after resuming activity (memory issue?)

Tags: android, memory, background, android-mapview, resume

My application has several components including a ListActivity and a MapActivity. I'm running into a weird problem where parts of those activities seem to be deallocated after resuming my application from background.

It's fairly deterministic.  I'll return home from my application, then run other application/go on browser and then return to my application. Then my MapView disappears and other components are gone or distorted.  Anyone run into something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Memory is taken back by the system if it goes `onPause()` and the memory is needed by other Apps (Garbage collection). You need to put `setContentView` of your activities in your `onResume()` method overload if you need it to resume the old status. Check the activity [life cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)